# How to get the current split index of test in Travis-CI?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

Just like $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER gives you the index of the build, is there a way to get the split index of the build?

For e.g.

```
Build 10234.23

$TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER == 10234
x == 23
```

How to get x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it as $TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER .

Source: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Environment-variables